# Specifying parameters in multiple QQ-plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution, quantile

I have melted a data set "mtotal", and want to make a QQ-plot against a normal distribution such that each variable in "mtotal" has its own specified parameters (mean() and sd()).
So far my code looks like this:

```
qplot(sample = value, data = mtotal, dist = qnorm) +
            facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

It makes a QQ-plot for each variable against a standard normal distribution.

mtotal looks like this:

```
"Variable"   "Value"    
 V1            10
 V1            11
 V1            8
 V1            12
 V2            100
 V2            102
  .            .
  .            .
  .            .
```

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of `mtotal` so we could help you better

Comment: Hi. It's not that i don't want to, but I am not allowed to show the information. But if it is any help, there are no factors. mtotal is a melt of total, which is a data frame consisting of 10 columns, and 26 rows. NA's do occur in most of the columns.

Comment: The mtotal has just listed all the columns on top of each other and the "value" column in mtotal is just the data from each column in total (NA's are omitted)